# Getting argument count of a function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm now using this code:

```
    size_t argc(std::function<Foo()>)
    { return 0; }

    size_t argc(std::function<Foo(Bar)>)
    { return 1; }

    size_t argc(std::function<Foo(Bar, Bar)>)
    { return 2; }

    size_t argc(std::function<Foo(Bar, Bar, Bar)>)
    { return 3; }

    // ...
```

But it is kinda ugly and limited (the user can't call `argc` with a function with any number of arguments.) Is there a better way to do it?

Note: the return type and the argument type are always the same. I know I can use templates to accept any type, but I don't need it.

Comment: umh the argument type is not always the same...

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I think that means they are always the same as in those examples: `Foo` for the return value, and `Bar` for all the arguments.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cleaner version of @Paolo's answer, usable with actual objects:

```
template<class R, class... Args>
constexpr unsigned arity(std::function<R(Args...)> const&){
  return sizeof...(Args);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The following will work for any arity, but accept arbitrary argument types:

```
template <typename T>
struct arity
{
};

template <typename... Args>
struct arity<std::function<Foo(Args...)>>
{
    static const int value = sizeof...(Args);
};
```

If you really want to constrain your argument type to be functions of type `Foo(Bar, Bar, ...)`, then you can do something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct arity
{
};

template <typename... Args>
struct const_tuple
{
};

template <>
struct const_tuple<>
{
    struct unsupported_function_type { };
};

template <typename... Args>
struct const_tuple<Bar, Args...>
{
    typedef typename const_tuple<Args...>::unsupported_function_type unsupported_function_type;
};

template <typename... Args>
struct arity<std::function<Foo(Args...)>> : public const_tuple<Args...>::unsupported_function_type
{
    static const int value = sizeof...(Args);
};
```

This will give you a compile error whenever arity is called with an unsupported function type.